# Can not copy Range to other Workbook in VBA office 2010

Tags: excel, copy, range

I have a strange issue I can not make run following subroutine :

```
Sub Copy_Workbook()
   Workbooks("book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Copy _ Workbooks("book2").Sheets(2).Range("a2")
End Sub
```

I have both excels `xlsm,` both are open and are open in the same instance.

I do receive the problem `Out of range`.

If anyone has any idea why it could not work can you please advice , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following sub will work.

```
Sub Copy_Workbook()
   Workbooks("book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Copy Workbooks("book2").Sheets(2).Range("a2")
End Sub
```

You have to confirm:

Two workbooks are open, `Book2` have at least 2 (two) sheets. Check all spelling are correct for sheet name.

Comment: Hello, can you please tell what problem your are facing with these codes.

Answer (score 0):

If your workbooks haven't been saved then referencing without their file extension will work.

Once you save them then you must include the extension.

You can confirm this by creating a new workbook then going to the Immediate pane in the VBA IDE and typing `?workbooks("Book1").name`.  It will return "Book1".

Save the workbook in .xlsm format.  Go back to the VBA IDE Immediate pane and re-execute `?workbooks("Book1").name`.  It will throw a "Subscript out of range" error.

Changing your code to:

```
   Sub Copy_Workbook()
   Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Copy _
   Workbooks("book2.xlsm").Sheets(2).Range("a2")
End Sub
```

will work!

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for a comments. I did exactly what you suggested however I have no any additional progress. Strange as your code and hints seems fine as well.